# How to disable monitoring virtual ethernet interfaces with vnstat?

Tags: networking, vnstat

How can I prevent `vnstat` from monitoring virtual interfaces for example created by docker?

`vnstat` monitors all network interfaces, including virtual network interfaces created by docker. We run a large docker stack that creates more than 20 virtual interfaces. We don't care about the statistics for these interfaces and never want to monitor them.

More fun, the virtual interfaces can change when the docker stack is rebooted. I can go through and delete all of these interfaces, but new interfaces will return after a restart.

I would like to not have to monitor the virtual interfaces ever again.

```
 vnstat --iflist
Available interfaces: br-228e34996f1f vethd1dad97 (10000 Mbit) vethf33f7fc (10000 Mbit) veth5cb2baf (10000 Mbit) veth301be0e (10000 Mbit) vethcbd2f8f (10000 Mbit) vethb43037e (10000 Mbit) veth9cb9511 (10000 Mbit) veth73cf6ad (10000 Mbit) vethf7126e4 (10000 Mbit) vethb9d4728 (10000 Mbit) veth67021c1 (10000 Mbit) veth95d0247 (10000 Mbit) vethf2126f8 (10000 Mbit) veth38768a8 (10000 Mbit) vethc1ded40 (10000 Mbit) veth6919d54 (10000 Mbit) vethbe63ff0 (10000 Mbit) vethc29d355 (10000 Mbit) docker0 veth0510ac7 (10000 Mbit)
```

(Some interfaces elided.)

This is on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
$ vnstat --version
vnStat 1.18 by Teemu Toivola <tst at iki dot fi>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I do not have vpnstat installed on Ubuntu 20.04.1 , so you could uninstall it (backup first)? you do not say which Ubintu version you have.